# Memory controller arbiters and memory accesses

Tags: intel-core-i7, ddr, microarchitecture

Does anyone know what the Arbiter would look like on a DDR memory controller? I was thinking that in order to perform memory access operation reordering for optimisation it may contain a ROB / scheduler / retire like architecture perhaps... Does anyone have an insight into the actual implementation?

Comment: Are you looking for a mechanism to arbitrate memory requests between channels/Ranks...?